# Replace <ul> instance with another one

Tags: jquery, css, replace, html-lists

I have data set in `<ul>` elements to show data on a state when it is clicked. By default, Id like there to be 3 columns that say "pick a state" and when the user clicks the given state, the data shows up. One issue that is coming into play is trying to replace a `<ul>` class with another `<ul>` without changing all 3? I have attached a JSFiddle and you can see more clearly what I am trying to do. I'd like to click one state and have the contents of that `<ul>` fill one of the default columns. For obvious reasons, the `<ul>` is a class and it changes all instances of that class, but I was wondering if there is a way to change 1 instance instead?

(http://jsfiddle.net/5xyrv1w1/)

Comment: Don't attempt to trick the system by formatting the link as code. Just include the code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not at all clear by your description or from your fiddle what you are trying to do. Are you trying to replace the <ul> that says 'Choose a state' with the State Data? If so, Why use a <ul> for the 'choose a state' at all. Just make it a div and append the selected state to the div. then add a class 'filled' to the div so you know it has state data inserted.

Comment: Correct. Either way, aren't you still injecting a <ul> with data into it? Or are you saying to add a div with data lines broken up by <br>'s? I just thought a list would be a cleaner way of showing the data semantically. Also, this is a bear bones version of what the final product will be. Depending on the data, the background color will be different so I feel like putting each data point in a list item would be worth it

Comment: I updated the Fiddle to show it a little more in detail. If I select New York, I'd like to New York data to replace 1 one of the "select a state" rows. X'ing them out is a whole different issue, but one I will work on once I can get them to replace the default columns

Answer (score 0):

Here look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xyrv1w1/2/

I've removed everything from your columns except your text. I've wrapped you data in a div. Now I can take the html from one div and make it the html for the other div. The hidden divs with the data are still there. I'm just using them to populate an empty 'Choose a state' div.

HTML:

```
<button class="NY">New York</button>
<button class="GA">Georgia</button>
<button class="FL">Florida</button>


            <div id="state-columns-container">
                <div class="pick-a-state-column" data-value="Choose a state">
                    Choose a state
                </div>

                <div class="pick-a-state-column" data-value="Choose a state">
                    Choose a state
                </div>

                <div class="pick-a-state-column" data-value="Choose a state">
                    Choose a state
                </div>


                <div id="NY" class="state-data">
                    <ul id="NY-state-column" data-value="newyork">
                        <li class="state-title-chosen univers-bold">
                            <span class="close-state">X</span>New York
                        </li>
                        <li>Some data</li>
                        <li>More data</li>
                        <li>A bit more</li>
                        <li>Last data</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="GA" class="state-data">
                    <ul id="GA-state-column" data-value="georgia">
                        <li class="state-title-chosen univers-bold">
                            <span class="close-state">X</span>Georgia
                        </li>
                        <li>Some data</li>
                        <li>More data</li>
                        <li>A bit more</li>
                        <li>Last data</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="FL" class="state-data">
                    <ul id="FL-state-column" data-value="florida">
                        <li class="state-title-chosen univers-bold">
                            <span class="close-state">X</span>Florida
                        </li>
                        <li>Some data</li>
                        <li>More data</li>
                        <li>A bit more</li>
                        <li>Last data</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#state-columns-container { 
    padding: 30px;    
}

.pick-a-state-column {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.pick-a-state-column ul { position: relative; }

.close-state {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 7px;;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.state-data { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        var $className = $(this).attr('class');
        var emptyCol = $('.pick-a-state-column').not('.filled')[0];
        if(emptyCol){
            $(emptyCol).html($('#' + $className).html());
            $(emptyCol).addClass('filled');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.close-state', function() {
        var $col = $(this).closest('.pick-a-state-column');
        $col.html($col.data('value'));
        $col.removeClass('filled');
    });
});
```

Comment: This works great - Thanks! I'd like to know more about the solution. I see you are adding a class of ".filled" to the column but there are no styles associated with it. Is there a specific reason for that?

Also, why did throwing the lists inside a div make the process more accessable? Would it have been harder to just replace <ul> elements instead of nesting them in a div? Either way, the solution seems to work. I will implement this and hopefully it works smooth. Cheers

Comment: The "filled" class is used on the button click handler to so that it picks a column that isn't already filled with data. If you click "New York" it will fill the first column with the data. Click 'Georgia' it will fill the second. You don't want it to overwrite the data in the first column so you have to find an empty column. so using $('.pick-a-state-column').not('.filled')[0]; gets the first column that is not filled.

Comment: Putting the <ul> inside divs does 2 things. First I added an ID to each that matches the value from the buttons making it easy to find the correct div from which to to get my data. But more importantly. It's easy to get the $(div).html() of the div, which is your entire <ul> element. Then use that as the html for the column $(column).html($(div).html());

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. If you like the answer please mark it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: How do I do that? I am new here and don't see a button to vote it as correct?